# How to integrate CKEditor into Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, fckeditor

Saw [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/fckeditor.aspx) at CodeProject for FCKEditor. Can someone explain what about the new version?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do actually.  First download the latest code from the [website](http://ckeditor.com/download) and extract it to a directory in your project (I choose /Scripts/ckeditor).  Then in your view, use the same code as in the "complete sample" in this [link](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration) and it should work.

Basically, the important steps are:

1. Make sure you include the
   ckeditor.js file in the head from your view or in your master
   page, however you want to do
   it. This needs to be the exact location within your project (I would use the find file  dialog that you can popup when editing a src attribute in visual studio so that it automatically links to the file).
2. Place the:

   <script type="text/javascript">
       CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
       </script>

   RIGHT AFTER your textarea and make
   sure the id of the textarea is the
   same in the CKEDITOR.replace()
   statement.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, you can not use CKEDITOR.DLL and its tags to, So you need to use ckeditor.js file.

Steps to use CKeditor in MVC3.

1. Include the ckeditor.js file to the razor page.
2. And then put  CKEDITOR.replace( 'textAreaId' );