# Is there any changes in web.config to insert data using ckeditor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Following is the code for `insert` into `database`. Using `ckeditor`, can any changes be done in `web.config` to `insert` data ?

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(Content cnt)
    {
        var dbContext = new MyDbDataContext();
        Table4 tb = new Table4();
        tb.Id = cnt.id;
        tb.Title = cnt.title;
        tb.Ptitle = cnt.page_title;
        tb.Url = cnt.url;
        tb.Description = cnt.description;
        dbContext.Table4s.InsertOnSubmit(tb);
        dbContext.SubmitChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what your asking.

Comment: Are you asking whether you need to modify your web.config to be able to use the ckeditor? No, you don't. CKEditor simply works with textbox contents it has no knowledge of your classes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1876521/2186023

Comment: I am trying to insert my content page using ckeditor. this code is successfully insert data in database. but at run time it shows tags like <p> <br/> and all that on browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should use @Html.Raw(YourItem) so your html tags will render as html
Like this

> @Html.Raw(item.Story)